# Adding attribute 'href' of existing links to other links with Jquery

Tags: jquery, href, attr

i want to create a mobile menu with Jquery but i'm failing with the reassignment of the href-attributes and text-attributes to the new links i created with Jquery. When i run console log on $(this).attr('href') and var $litext = $(this).text() everything seems fine. I just cant figure it out how to connect the new links with the two elements.

I made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/14htwa2u/1/

```
var $navigation = '<div id="wrapper"><ul><li></li></ul></div>';
var $links = '<a class="dot"></a>';
$($navigation).append($links);

$('a').each(function(){


// Atrribut href
var $attribut = $(this).attr('href');

console.log($attribut);
// Text
var $litext = $(this).text();
console.log($litext);
// Verknüpfung
$($links).val($(this).attr('href', $attribut));

$($links).text($($litext).text());


console.log($links);
});
```

Thx 4 your help

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do... But I can see that you aren't setting any href to another link than to it's own, because of this line `$($links).val($(this).attr('href', $attribut))`; $attribut is the href the $(this) already has! - and you try to set `$($links).val(*here*)` the object as text??

Comment: "*Thx 4 your help*" - you're not being charged per character, this question is not SMS: could you edit your question to use actual words, which might just clarify your question and earn you some responses.

Comment: Oh, now I used my soothsayer skills: you only want to wrap your navigation! Have a look at [jquery.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) - But why you don't try to show / hide the navigation using only a few lines of css and maybe a bit of jQuery? - doing this you can also divide mobile and desktop browsers.

Comment: @Johannes: Sorry, that i made the question unclear. And yes your advice would be a solution. But i am very new to Jquery and this code ist just for practicing. But thx :)

Comment: @Steve Even if you are a German you should comment your code in English (because then you start naming your variables and functions also in English what avoids problems with äöü and so on). And don't use `$` for every variable you create; actually you can do that, but it's confusing a lot if you write bigger codes in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create each new link new.

But at first, we append the list to the body and then we append each link with it's own li-element:

```
$('<div id="wrapper"><ul></ul></div>').appendTo($("body"));

$("a").each(function () {
    // get the href-attribute and the link-text
    var
    attribute = $(this).attr("href"),
    text = $(this).text();

    // log href and text
    console.log("attribute: ", attribute, " | text: ", text);

    // create new link with li in new navigation
    $('<li><a href="'+ attribute +'" class="dot">'+ text +'</a></li>').appendTo($("#wrapper ul"))
})
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/14htwa2u/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change value of `href` attribute of anchor tag for which we need to use `attr()` function not `val()` function:

```
var $navigation = '<div id="wrapper"><ul><li></li></ul></div>';
var $links = '<a class="dot"></a>';
$($navigation).find('li').append($links);// may be you want to append inside list

$('a').each(function(){


// Atrribut href
var $attribut = $(this).attr('href');

console.log($attribut);
// Text
var $litext = $(this).text();
console.log($litext);
// Verknüpfung
$($links).attr('href',$attribut); //use attr instead of val

$($links).text($($litext).text());


console.log($links);
});
```

Comment: You should add description in the answer instead of just posting corrected code

Comment: thx 4 your advice. i already tried the .attr on $links but i didnt work. i also tried your suggestion for $($navigation).find('li').append($links) but unfortunately it didnt work either.